# My game collision system doesn't work on more than one tile

Tags: java, collision-detection, polygon, collision

I'm working on a collision system for my game, however I can't get it to work, if I add more than one wall (which is the object I'm rendering) the collision system doesn't work and I can get through the block.

However if I leave only one wall the collision works correctly, or if at the end of the loop I add a break;
the collision works but only on the first wall of the map, the others don't get the collision.

Would anyone know how to solve this? I've been trying to solve it for 2 days and I couldn't.

```
    public boolean checkCollisionWall(int xnext, int ynext){
        int[] xpoints1 = {xnext+3,xnext+3,xnext+4,xnext+3,xnext+3,xnext+4,xnext+10,xnext+11,xnext+11,xnext+10,xnext+11,xnext+11};
        int[] ypoints1 = {ynext+0,ynext+8,ynext+9,ynext+11,ynext+12,ynext+15,ynext+15,ynext+12,ynext+11,ynext+9,ynext+8,ynext+0};
        int npoints1 = 12;
        Polygon player = new Polygon(xpoints1,ypoints1,npoints1);
        Area area = new Area(player);
        for(int i = 0; i < Game.walls.size(); i++){
            Wall atual = Game.walls.get(i);
            int[] xpoints2 = {atual.getX(),atual.getX(),atual.getX()+16,atual.getX()+16};
            int[] ypoints2 = {atual.getY(),atual.getY()+16,atual.getY()+16,atual.getY()};
            int npoints2 = 4;
            Polygon Wall = new Polygon(xpoints2,ypoints2,npoints2);
            area.intersect(new Area(Wall));
            if(area.isEmpty()){
                return true;
            }
        }
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `Area` class works as expected?

Comment: The Area works normal and the collision works as well, however if I add more than one wall to the map, the collision stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is this call:

```
area.intersect(new Area(Wall));
```

Here's the JavaDoc for that method:

> public void intersect(Area rhs)
>
> Sets the shape of this Area to the intersection of its current shape
> and the shape of the specified Area. The resulting shape of this Area
> will include only areas that were contained in both this Area and also
> in the specified Area.

So `area`, which represents the shape of your player, is going to be modified by each test with a wall, which is why it's only working with one wall.

You could fix the issue by simply making the player `Area` the argument of the call, as in:

```
Area wallArea = new Area(Wall); 
wallArea.intersect(area);
if(wallArea.isEmpty()){
    return true;
}
```

By the way, this logic is reversed isn't it. Don't you want to check that the resulting area is not empty, i.e. there was an overlap between the player and the wall?

The other option, if each `Wall` is actually a rectangle, would be to use the this `Area` method instead:

> public boolean intersects(double x,
> double y,
> double w,
> double h)
>
> Tests if the interior of the Shape intersects the interior of a
> specified rectangular area. The rectangular area is considered to
> intersect the Shape if any point is contained in both the interior of
> the Shape and the specified rectangular area.

Something like this:

```
if(area.intersects(atual.getX(), atual.getY(), 16, 16)) {
    return true;
}
```

As this avoids the creation of an `Area` object for each wall, and the intersection test is going to be much simpler, and faster.